# SQL query to select parent and child names

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table with the following structure -

```
Category {Id, Name, ParentId}
```

I have values like this -

```
id  name               parentid
-------------------------------
1   Technology Focus   NULL
2   Tools              1
3   Database           1
```

How do I write a query that displays like this -

```
name (parent)      name (child)             
--------------------------------
Technology Focus   Tools
Technology Focus   Database
etc..
```

I believe I need to use the Group By clause but I'm not quite getting it.

Comment: What is special about "technology Focus"?  Is it a category?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just want to group them according to their parent category (name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if i'm looking at that correctly, i think you just need

```
select parent.name, child.name 
from category child
  inner join category parent
    on parent.id = child.parentid
```

Comment: Damnit, you beat me by about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table on itself like this:

```
select Cat.Name, Par.Name
from category as cat
inner join category par on cat.id = par.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to implement at tree-like structure in SQL, then this, kinda, is the wrong way to do this.

You should use two tables to implement a tree:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
   category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(40),
   PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
);
CREATE TABLE Tree (
   ancestor INT NOT NULL,
   descendant INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(ancestor, descendant),
   FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES Categories(category_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES Categories(category_id)
);
```

This structure (know as *Closure Table* )is easier to maintain (preform updates, rearrange structure , etc. ).

Then you select the data like:

```
SELECT 
   parent.name AS parent,
   item.name AS item
FROM Categories AS parent
LEFT JOIN Tree AS path ON parent.category_id = path.ancestor
LEFT JOIN Categories AS item ON item.category_id = path.descendant
WHERE parent.category_id = 1
```

Anyway , read about *[Closure Tables](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html)*, you will understand why ..